# Which methods would you use in case of binary data?

Tags: model, binary-data

The dataset is a full ranked binary dataset. Therefore, `Y = 1 or 0`and `X's = 1 or 0`. Y represents whether a car has an engine failure or not. `X` represents the features of the car, for example `X1` is engine type A, `X2` engine type B, `X3` gear type etc.  I want to know from your experience, which models work well on those type of datasets. I read somewhere, that `LDA` or `KNN`are not recommended, as well as `SVM`.

Which information criterion would you use for forward selection? `AIC`, `BIC`..?

The data looks like this

```
       Engine_A Engine_B Engine_C Color_R Color_B Color_G  Y_Failure
Car1     1         0        0        0       1       0         1
Car2     0         1        0        1       0       0         0 
Car3     0         1        0        0       0       1         1
```

Would you factorize all variables **X** and **Y**?

Comment: This is not answerable without a lot more detail about your specific problem.

Comment: What is the **goal** of your analysis? Sample size? How many predictors? ... meanwhile, if you are interested in modeling the probability of $Y=1$, conditional on $x$, look into logistic regression ...

Comment: The goal is to predict **Y** as good as possible. I already used logistic regression. Let me ask the other way around: which models are not suitable for that particular problem?